# Slope Plot with Quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, differential-equations

I am trying to plot a slope field plot given a system of differential equations.
In this case, my main goal is to plot a slope field of S versus I1 or I2. I would like
to also be able to have a fixed arrow length, but I don't know how to go about that.

I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

# Initial Conditions (Suscetible, type 1 infectives, type 2 infectives, and recovered)
(S0, I1_0, I2_0, R0) = (40, 2, 8, 0)

# Constants (infection rate for type 1 infectives, infection rate for type 2 infectives,
# percentage of infectives that are type 1, and recovery rate for both infective classes)
(r1, r2, beta, gamma) = (0.02, 0.03, 0.8, 0.95)
N = S0 + I1_0 + I2_0 + R0 # Initial population

# System of Differential Equations
def model(y, t, beta, gamma):
    dSdt = -(r2*I1 + r2*I2) * S
    dI1dt = beta * (r2*I1 + r2*I2) * S - (gamma * I1)
    dI2dt = (1 - beta) * (r2*I1 + r2*I2) * S - (gamma * I2)
    dRdt = gamma * (I1 + I2)
    S, I1, I2, R = y
    return dSdt, dI1dt, dI2dt, dRdt

# Number of days
t = np.linspace(0, 30, 365)

# Initial conditions for integration
y0 = S0, I1_0, I2_0, R0

# Integrate
sol = odeint(model, y0, t, args=(beta, gamma))
S, I1, I2, R = sol.T

# Slope plot
x = np.arange(0, N, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, N, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
f = -(r2*I1 + r2*I2) * S

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(X, Y, sol[:, 1], f)
plt.show()
```

But of course, the code is not producing a plot of any kind. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you are having?

Comment: I manged to get it to show something using x, y instead of X, Y (i.e. no `np.meshgrid()`) and rdefying x, y in such a way that the length is the same as sol[:, 1] and f. I know quiver is supposed to take a meshgrid, but the beheaviour was changed with the passage to Martplotlib 3.2 (I think) which might explain the issue with the legacy examples? I'm not expert enough to have an answer on that